# Knowing sub-class type in super-class function

Tags: java, class, abstract-class

I try to make an algorithm for people at a local register who would like to pay their anual tax for properties. I have an abstract class for Properties, which has essential variables and methods for each other type of property. The problem is, I would like to print for a known Client all the properties and I don't know how to get the type of property through the superclass

I've thought about declaring another variable in the Properties class which would tell me if I have a rang or not, then, knowing this, I would have a Building or a Field. But that doesn't respect the polymorphism property. If I would introduce a new type of property, I would need to change everything.
I am pretty new to java and I have no other clue. Thank you.

```
public class Client {
private int CNP;
private String Name;
private int totalSum;
private Properties[] properties;

public Client(String Name, Properties[] properties) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.properties = properties;
    setTotalSum(properties);
    CNP = 0;
}
public Client(int CNP, Properties[] properties) {
    Name = "No Name Specified";
    this.properties = properties;
    setTotalSum(properties);
    this.CNP = CNP;
}
public Client(String Name, int CNP, Properties[] properties) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.properties = properties;
    setTotalSum(properties);
    this.CNP = CNP;
}

public String toString() {
    String s = "Contribuabil:   " + getName() + "\n" +
            "Proprietati:   \n";
    for(Properties property:properties) {
        s += property.toString();
    }
    s += "Suma totala:   " + getTotalSum();
    return s;
}
```

The Properties class

```
abstract class Properties {
private String nameAdress;
private int number;
private int paySum;

public Properties(String nameAdress, int number) {
    this.nameAdress = nameAdress;
    this.number = number;
}

public void setPaySum(int surface) {
    paySum = 500 * surface;
}
public void setPaySum(int surface, int rang) {
    paySum = (350 * surface) / rang;
}
public int getPaySum() {
    return paySum;
}
public String toString() {
 //here I would like to print the type of property;
}
```

The sub-class Building

```
public class Building extends Properties {
private int surface;

public Building(String nameAdress, int number, int surface) {
    super(nameAdress, number);
    this.surface = surface;
    setPaySum(surface);
}
```

The sub-class Field

```
public class Field extends Properties {
private int surface;
private int rang;

public Field(String nameAdress, int number, int surface, int rang) {
    super(nameAdress, number);
    this.surface = surface;
    this.rang = rang;
    setPaySum(surface, rang);
}
```

Comment: It is common for a `toString()` method to make use of `getClass().getName()` or `getClass().getSimpleName()`.

Comment: Thank you very much @VGR!! I did not know about this. It's perfect now